# sending mail from personnal component = ok with Joomla!3.4.5 but nok with Joomla!3.6.2

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, jmail, joomla-mail

For debugging, I tried these lines:

```
jimport('joomla.mail.mail');

$m = new JMail();
$m->SetFrom('myAddressMail@xx.fr','myName');
$m->AddReplyTo('myAddressMail@xx.fr','myFirstName');
$m->sendMail('myAddressMail@xx.fr','test', 'myAddressMail@xx.fr','test', 'essai', true,'myAddressMail@xx.fr');
```

It works within Joomla 3.4.5 but not within Joomla 3.6.2 (same configuration = php mail - send Test Mail works).

I think that changes were made in `librairies/joomla/mail/mail.php` but which ones / how to use `sendMail()` ?

Thanks for help

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions

Comment: Thanks Lodder. I use the mentionned tutorial and it works now.

Comment: Please post your answer (with code snippet) below and mark it as accepted so other know it has been solved ;)

Comment: I think your problems were maybe caused by a change in the addReplyTo where it used to take an array, but then changed to take one or two strings.  I think this in https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/commit/e013daec2507761b3ac0712704fff404f350b852

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the code that works :

```
//preparation et envoi du mail
$m=JFactory::getMailer();

//provenance du mail
$sender = array('myEmailAddress','myName');
$m->setSender($sender);

//destibnataires du mail
$m->addRecipient($to); //an array of emails

//sujet du message
$m->setSubject($subject); 

//encodage du mail
$m->isHTML(true);
$m->Encoding='base64';

//le corps du message
$m->setBody($message); 
//$message = a string with html tag

//envoi du mail
$send = $m->Send();
```

Thanks Lodder and AndyGaskell for yours contributions